# Markdown fails to ignore URLs in inline code if multiple URLs are present

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

It seems that if there are several URLs in an inline code block, only the first one is not "linkified":

`http://stackoverflow.com/  http://superuser.com/  http://serverfault.com/`

There are two spaces between each URL. If I put only one space between each, only the middle one is linked:

`http://stackoverflow.com/ http://superuser.com/ http://serverfault.com/`

**Update:** Maybe someone is wondering why I just don't format such lines as block code. I often mark URLs as inline code so that they get not highlighted as comments which makes them easier to read then. I assume I could use one of the language hint `<!-- lang -->` comments, but formatting as inline code is quicker ;)

Comment: Is reading `http://stackoverflow.com` really easier than reading [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @John: I'm talking about situations where URLs are examples, like as input for regular expressions. Often, these URLs are not valid anyway, like http://one.two.three.something (`http://one.two.three.something`)... linking them does not make sense. [This was the question where I discovered this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842838/218196)

Comment: That makes sense. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed on [both](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=99d80ddb110ad9ba7b67302312a3f2ceefe17308) [sides](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=debd6d9cf0bbfba9fbdec813747b2b9971f4bcc4) of the fence (next build). Thanks!